# Get Error Message in SQL Server stored procedure to VB.NET program

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 Express like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dtUmum.prCoba
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 1/0;
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @varErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), @varErrorSeverity INT, @varErrorState INT;
    SELECT @varErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @varErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @varErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
    RAISERROR(@varErrorMessage,@varErrorSeverity,@varErrorState);
END CATCH;
END
```

If I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio like this :

```
EXECUTE dtUmum.prCoba;
```

I get this error in the messages tab :

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure prCoba, Line 33
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

I want this message show in my vb.net windows form program.

In my form, I add 1 button and 1 datagridview.

My code in method `button_click` like this :

```
Try
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDB;Integrated Security=True")
        cn.Open()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "dtUmum.prCoba"
            Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                da.Fill(dt)
                da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source)
                Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        End Using
        cn.Close()
    End Using
Catch SQLex As SqlException
    Dim SSS As SqlError
    MsgBox("Count = " & SQLex.Errors.Count)
    For Each SSS In SQLex.Errors
        MsgBox(SSS.Message)
    Next
End Try
```

This code not show error in my vb.net program.

So, what code should I write to show the error in my stored procedure ?

Comment: Instead of using a DataAdapter, have you tried filling the DataTable with `dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())`? Ref: MarkN's penultimate post at [SqlDataAdapter and RAISERRORs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad135c3f-2afb-40aa-9eff-28cff08514c3/sqldataadapter-and-raiserrors?forum=adodotnetdataproviders).

Comment: Does the first MessageBox (you should be using this in .Net rather than the old VB6 MsgBox anyway) show the count? Normally, I don't bother with that or a `For Each ... Next` loop. My error handlers typically would just do `MessageBox.Show(SQLex.ToString)`. The `ToString` shows full detail of the exception so it's not very pretty while `Message` property shows just the message description.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from Andrew Morton comment.
I use dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()) and it is work.